# Angular 2 Estilos css no son aplicados

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Tengo el siguiente componente

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './views/noticias/noticias.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./views/noticias/noticias.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  numeroNoticias:number = 200;
  title = 'app';
}
```

el cual si me toma el html que es y todo, nunca me marca error de que los css estan mal o de que no los encuentra, simplemente nunca los aplica, debo hacer algo màs?

Comment: La ruta verificaste que si es correcta?

Answer (score 1):

El archivo .css debería estar al mismo nivel que tu archivo .ts. Para evitar confusiones debes hacer uso del cli de angular para generar componentes

```
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-root',nent.html',  
  templateUrl: './noticias.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./noticias.component.css']
})
```

Otro error puede ser la nomenclatura, comprueba si se llaman igual.

Y siempre puedes hacer uso de styles.css para usar clases globales dentro de tu proyecto

Saludos!